# Multiple array values to table php

Tags: php, arrays

Hello how to show values in table when i have a three arrays?
I have 3 three arrays: urls,name,rok

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [urls] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => /film/Marsjanin-2015-715533
                    )        
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => /film/Pi%C4%99%C4%87dziesi%C4%85t+twarzy+Greya-2015-655761
                    )        
            )        
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => Marsjanin
                    )        
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => Pięćdziesiąt twarzy Greya
                    )        
            )        
        [rok] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => (2015)
                    )        
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => (2015)
                    )
            )
    )
```

I want show values in table like this but  missing $valu3  to third row in table, how to do?

```
urls                             name                      rok
/film/Marsjanin-2015-715533      Marsjanin                 (2015)
/film/Pi%C4%99%C4%87dziesi%C4%   Pięćdziesiąt twarzy Greya (2015)
```

This is my code:

```
foreach($results as $itemz => $valuez) {    
  foreach($valuez as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
      if ($itemz=='urls'){
        $valu1[] = str_replace("/film/", "film/", $value2);
      }

      if($itemz=='name'){
        $valu2[] = $value2;
      }

      if($itemz=='rok'){
        $valu3[] = $value2;
      }
    }
  }     
}

$Result = array_combine($valu1, $valu2);
//echo '<pre>'; print_r($Result); echo '</pre>';
foreach($Result as $key1 => $value1) {
  echo '
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" value="'.$key1.'" name="list[]" /></th>
      <th>'.$value1.' ()</th><th>'.$rating.'</th>
      <th><a href="'.$key1.'" target="_blank">'.$value1.'</a></th>
      <th>'.$genres.'</th><th>Importuj</th>
    </tr>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an object that contains three arrays with identical index number, so you can perform only one `foreach` loop in this way:

```
foreach( $results->urls as $key => $array )
{
    echo $results->urls[$key]['key'];
    echo $results->name[$key]['key'];
    echo $results->rok[$key]['key'];
}
```

All the first part of code can be deleted. In the example above I simply echo values, without reproducing your html structure, because I don't understand it (you have two `$value1` and a lot of `<th>`... ), but you can easily change it in your preferred way, like this:

```
echo '<td>'.$results->urls[$key]['key'].'</td>';
( etc... )
```